# Remove console.logs with Webpack & Uglify

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, uglifyjs

I am trying to remove `console.logs` with Webpack's Uglify plugin but it seems that Uglify plugin that comes bundled with Webpack doesn't have that option, its not mentioned in the documentation.

I am initializing uglify from webpack like this:

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
```

My understanding is that I can use standalone Uglify lib to get all the options, but I don't know which one?

The problem is that `drop_console` isn't working.

Answer (score 97):

With `UglifyJsPlugin` we can handle **comments, warnings, console logs** but it will not be a good idea to remove all these in development mode. First check whether you are running `webpack` for `prod env or dev env`, if it is `prod env` then you can remove all these, like this:

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

plugins: !debug ? [
   new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({

     // Eliminate comments
        comments: false,

    // Compression specific options
       compress: {
         // remove warnings
            warnings: false,

         // Drop console statements
            drop_console: true
       },
    })
]
: []
```

Reference: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#compressor-options

**UPDATE 2019**
Need to use terser plugin now for ES6 support in webpack v4
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin#terseroptions

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        sourceMap: true, // Must be set to true if using source-maps in production
        terserOptions: {
          compress: {
            drop_console: true,
          },
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: I am using drop_console: true but it doesn't remove console logs.
Firs i though that webpacks uglify plugin doesn't come with those option, because there is no mention of them on official webpack docks.
But it seems i am using correct uglify plugin, just drop_console doesn't work.

here is my webpack config: http://pastebin.com/tvymXfZ0

Comment: Try this: http://hastebin.com/kunokasenu.js
This is my prod config, i also have separate dev config.

Comment: i m using the same code, everything is working fine when i build it with webpack -p.

Comment: This won't work in Webpack 4: `webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin has been removed, please use config.optimization.minimize instead.`

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101152/webpack-v4-remove-console-logs-with-webpack-uglify

Comment: so `config.optimization.minimize` or `config.optimization.minimizer`?

Comment: need to add `minimize: true` as mentioned in official docs e.g: `optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],
  },`

Answer (score 60):

Try [drop_console](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#compressor-options):

```
plugins: [
    new Webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        drop_console: true,
      }
    }
]
```

**Update:** For webpack **v4** it has changed a little:

```
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

...

optimization: {
  minimizer: [
    new UglifyJSPlugin({
      uglifyOptions: {
        compress: {
          drop_console: true,
        }
      }
    })
  ]
}
```

I personally think console logs (especially `console.error`) are very useful on prod and think it's a good idea to keep them. If you really want to drop specific console functions such as just `console.log` you should use `pure_funcs` option e.g. `pure_funcs: ['console.log']` and this will drop `console.log` since pure functions do not produce side effects then Uglify can discard ones ***not assigned*** to anything.

```
optimization: {
  minimizer: [
    new UglifyJSPlugin({
      uglifyOptions: {
        compress: {
          // Drop only console.logs but leave others
          pure_funcs: ['console.log'],
        },
        mangle: {
          // Note: I'm not certain this is needed.
          reserved: ['console.log']
        }
      }
    })
  ]
}
```

**For TerserJS** (Uglify is deprecated and does not support new JS features you should NOT use it)

```
optimization: {
  minimizer: [
    new TerserPlugin({
      terserOptions: {
        compress: {
            drop_console: true
        }
      }
    })
  ]
}
```

As discussed you can also use `pure_funcs` alternatively.

Comment: That is exactly what i tried but it doesn't do anything.
I can see it uglifies the code but it doesn't remove console logs.

Comment: I'm actually trying to do the opposite, and unfortunately setting `drop_console: false` hasn't helped me.

Comment: This won't work in Webpack 4: `webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin has been removed, please use config.optimization.minimize instead.`

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101152/webpack-v4-remove-console-logs-with-webpack-uglify

Comment: Do I use both terser and uglify?

Comment: Const doesn't work when you build, since UglifyJS doesn't understand ES6.

Comment: You should use TerserJS nowadows NOT UglifyJS, it supports ES6+ features and is actively maintained

Comment: It doesn't work! Neither Terser nor Uglify. The logs are not removed. I have been trying since yesterday!

Comment: // Drop only console.logs but leave others
pure_funcs: ['console.log'],


// remove all  console, includes(console.log, console.error, console.warn, ...adn son on)
drop_console: true,

Comment: The TerserPlugin approach worked for me but only in `mode:"production"` or without a mode specified

Answer (score 11):

You can use `terser-webpack-plugin` **compress** option **pure_funcs** parameter to selectively drop console functions and keep the ones that you want such as console.error.

I was using "webpack": "^4.39.3" and "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.2".

Steps:
 1. npm install terser-webpack-plugin --save-dev
 2. modify your webpack.config to set `TerserPlugin` as a minimizer for optimization option.

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env) => {
    return [{
        entry: '...',
        mode: 'production',
        output: {...},
        plugins: [...],
        optimization: {
            'minimize': true,
            minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
                terserOptions: { 
                    compress: { 
                        pure_funcs: [
                            'console.log', 
                            'console.info', 
                            'console.debug', 
                            'console.warn'
                        ] 
                    } 
                 }
            })],
        },
        module: {...}
    }];
};
```

Comment: This does indeed hide the console logs for production mode in Webpack5. However, in development mode also, it is hiding the console logs. Is there a way to disable the minimizer for development mode?

Answer (score 8):

This is the new syntax for Webpack v4:

```
optimization: {
  minimizer: [
    new UglifyJSPlugin({
      uglifyOptions: {
        compress: {
          drop_console: true
        },
        output: {
          comments: false
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
},
```

Answer (score 6):

For uglifyjs-webpack-plugin, wrap options inside an uglifyOptions object:

```
    plugins: [
    new UglifyJSPlugin({
        uglifyOptions: {
            compress: {
                drop_console: true
            }
        }
    })
]
```

Answer (score 4):

I have added a comprehensive answer for webpack v4 with debug configuration

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

.....
optimization: {
        minimizer: !debug ? [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({

                    // Compression specific options
                    uglifyOptions: {
                        // Eliminate comments
                        comments: false,

                        compress: {
                            // remove warnings
                                warnings: false,

                            // Drop console statements
                                drop_console: true
                        },
                    }

                })
            ]
            : []
    }
```

My scripts in package.json are like so:

```
"webpackDev": "npm run clean && export NODE_ENV=development && npx webpack",
"webpackProd": "npm run clean && export NODE_ENV=production && npx webpack -p"
```

Answer (score 4):

this is what I've done to remove alert() and console.log() from my codes.
global_defs => replace alerts with console.log
then drop_console removes all console.logs and now nothing shows up in my browser console

```
     new UglifyJsPlugin({
      uglifyOptions: {
        compress: {
          global_defs: {
            "@alert": "console.log",
          },
          drop_console: true
        }
      }
    }),
```

plugin versions:

> ```
> "webpack":3.12.0,
> "webpack-cli": "^3.0.3",
> "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.5",
> ```

Right now uglifyjs-webpack-plugin v1.2.6 has been released and I used latest documentations for this one, So I suppose there wont be any problem with latest plugin too.

Answer (score 3):

## webpack 4.x remove `console.log` solutions

1. only remove the `console.log` but leave other consoles (recommend ✅)

> pure_funcs: ['console.log']

```js
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    // ...
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJSPlugin({
                uglifyOptions: {
                    compress: {
                        pure_funcs: [
                            'console.log',
                            // 'console.error',
                            // 'console.warn',
                            // ...
                        ],
                    },
                    // Make sure symbols under `pure_funcs`,
                    // are also under `mangle.reserved` to avoid mangling.
                    mangle: {
                        reserved: [
                            'console.log',
                            // 'console.error',
                            // 'console.warn',
                            // ...
                        ],
                    },
                },
            }),
        ],
    },
    // ...
}
```

2. remove all consoles, includes(console.log, console.error, console.warn, ...and so on) (not recommend ‍♂️)

> drop_console: true,

```js
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    // ...
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJSPlugin({
                uglifyOptions: {
                    compress: {
                        drop_console: true,
                    },
                },
            }),
        ],
    },
    // ...
}
```

### all consoles

> Chrome Google, Version 88.0.4324.192 (Official Build) (x86_64)

[image]

### refs

https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS#compress-options

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If TerserPlugin's drop_console does not applied, you probably check your build file's extension!
I'm struggling with this with my react project and solved it by adding test regex property for .js ([default is .mjs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/))

```js
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i, // you should add this property
        terserOptions: {
          compress: {
            drop_console: true,
            drop_debugger: true,
            pure_funcs: ['console.log', 'console.info'], // Delete console
          },
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this is better and works
    const UglifyEsPlugin = require('uglify-es-webpack-plugin')

```
module.exports = {
plugins: [
        new UglifyEsPlugin({
            compress:{
                drop_console: true
            }
        }),
] 
}
```