# How to get rid of console log

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I wrote a web app using React, and I build it using Webpack. But in the production build, I want to get rid of all the console log statement because I don't want people to see some information such as their UID. Is there anything I can config in Webpack so that it will automatically get rid of all the console log? I tried p flag but it didn't do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove console.logs with Webpack & Uglify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040266/remove-console-logs-with-webpack-uglify)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the UglifyJsPlugin with this configuration:

```
 new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false,
                screw_ie8: true,
                conditionals: true,
                unused: true,
                comparisons: true,
                sequences: true,
                dead_code: true,
                evaluate: true,
                if_return: true,
                join_vars: true,
                drop_console: true,
                drop_debugger: true,
                global_defs: {
                    __REACT_HOT_LOADER__: undefined // eslint-disable-line no-undefined
                }
            },
            minimize: true,
            debug: false,
            sourceMap: true,
            output: {
                comments: false
            },

        }),
```

You can see the whole config file here: https://github.com/jquintozamora/react-typescript-webpack2-cssModules-postCSS/blob/master/webpack/webpack.config.prod.js