# Is there a way to add script like console.log(var) only on webpack dev server for development purpose?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-3

For development purpose,

Is there a way to add script like console.log(var) only on webpack-dev-server?

Not for webpack -p mode.

Comment: Which webpack are you using, 2 or 3?

Comment: @msanford Im using 3.3 latest

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040266/remove-console-logs-with-webpack-uglify

Comment: @msanford Thank you  for the link! it is really helpful. I'm just curious, is there a way to have other script in dev server mode, not only console.log.

Comment: Looks like it: the second answer from the above-linked question suggests `yahoo strip-loader`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41040432/114900