# How to disable console logs while running reactjs + meteor application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, meteor, react-router

When running a Meteor + ReactJs app on the production server, I want to disable all the console logs and error statements from popping up.

Is there any way to do so? Something like setting a variable in the `settings.json` file or something like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to quickly and conveniently disable all console.log statements in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215392/how-to-quickly-and-conveniently-disable-all-console-log-statements-in-my-code)

Comment: If you use any JS bundle, you should check for drop console.log plugin. For webpack, check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040266/remove-console-logs-with-webpack-uglify). I found other node modules for other JS bundles like gulp.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to redefine your `console.log` and `console.error` to empty functions

```
console.log = (msg) => { };
console.error = (msg) => { };

console.log("nothing appears!");
console.error("neither here!");
```