# Change console.log() for production deployments?

Tags: angular

I'm outputting a lot a internal info through extensive use of `console.log()`. Is there a way to change the `.log()` command for my `--prod` builds in Angular?

Comment: you can comment all the unnecessary logs using find & replace functionality in your code editor

Comment: If you have using tslint, you could have set the `no-console`  rule, which would reminded you to remove the excessive console.logs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove console.logs with Webpack & Uglify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040266/remove-console-logs-with-webpack-uglify). In short: Use `TerserPlugin` with the `drop_console` option set to true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building off of Yash Rami's answer, I found that I needed to use `window.console.log()` in main.ts.

```
if(environment.production){
    window.console.log = function() {}
    enableProdMode();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to write this in main.ts. I hope it helps you out

```
      import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
      import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
      import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
      import { environment } from './environments/environment';

      if (environment.production) {
        console.log = function() {}   // this will be disable all the logs in production mode 
        enableProdMode();
      }

      platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
```