# How do you remove console.log from a build using the JS Quasar Framework?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, quasar-framework

I am trying the Quasar Framework (for those not familiar, it's based on Vue) and it's going well. However I've tried running a build (npm run build) and get repeated:

> error  Unexpected console statement  no-console

... so the build fails because it sees *console.log(...)* and is not happy. My options:

1. don't use *console.log* in development. But it's handy.
2. comment out the eslint rule that presumably enforces that, so letting *console.log* into production. But that's not ideal for performance/security.
3. have the build automatically remove any *console.log*. That's what I'm after.

But how?

I took a look at the build https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/build-commands and it mentions using webpack internally and UglifyJS too. Given that, I found this answer for removing console.log in a general Vue/webpack project: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/issues/21

... but if that's how, where does that go within Quasar since there is no webpack config file? I imagine in the quasar.conf.js file (since I see an 'extendWebpack' line in there - sounds promising). Or is there a better way to do it? How do other people remove *console.log* in production when using Quasar? Or handle logging without it?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040266/remove-console-logs-with-webpack-uglify

Comment: @RobertNiestroj Thanks. I found that page too before asking, but that also uses a direct webpack. It's not clear how to fit in with a Quasar framework build which doesn't have that webpack config file to just copy into

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-build

`quasar.conf.js`:

```js
module.exports = function (ctx) {
  return {
  ...
    build: {
    ...
      uglifyOptions: {
        compress: { drop_console: true }
      }
    },
  }
}
```

The above will result in configuring terser plugin with the following:

```js
          terserOptions: {
            compress: {
            ...
              drop_console: true
            },
```

(https://github.com/terser/terser#compress-options)

(you can see the generated config with `quasar inspect -c build -p optimization.minimizer`)

You still also need to remove the eslint rule to avoid build errors, see https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/5529

Note:
If you want instead to configure webpack directly use:

`quasar.conf.js`:

```js
module.exports = function (ctx) {
  return {
  ...
    build: {
    ...
      chainWebpack (chain) {
        chain.optimization.minimizer('js').tap(args => {
          args[0].terserOptions.compress.drop_console = true
          return args
        })
      }
    },
  }
}
```

It will do the same as above.

See https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/handling-webpack

and https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain#config-optimization-minimizers-modify-arguments

https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/blob/dev/app/lib/webpack/create-chain.js#L315

Comment: I'm trying this but still console log coming in production.

Answer (score 0):

1 Edit package.json in Vue's project what had created it before.

2 Then find "rules": {}.

3 Change to this "rules":{"no-console":0}.

4 if you Vue server in on, off it and run it again. Then the issue will be done.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative I can suggest using something like [loglevel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loglevel) instead of `console.log`. It's quite handy and allows you to control the output.