# Quasar app does not remove console.log() for production builds

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, quasar-framework

I am unable to get my Quasar app to remove the `console.log()` for production builds.

I have read answers on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58561195/how-do-you-remove-console-log-from-a-build-using-the-js-quasar-framework), [Quasar forums](https://forum.quasar-framework.org/topic/2655/how-to-drop-console-statements-in-production/8) and [GitHub](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/discussions/10386). All of these claim to fix the issue but I am still getting `console.log`'s and warnings.

I have tried a few different combinations of

**quasar.conf.js**

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
    build: {
      uglifyOptions: {
        compress: { drop_console: true },
      },
      devtool: 'source-map',
      sourceMap: true,      
      chainWebpack(chain) {
        chain.optimization.minimizer('js').tap((args) => {
          args[0].terserOptions.compress.drop_console = true
          args[0].terserOptions.compress.drop_debugger = true
          return args
        })
      }
    }
}
```

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
    build: {
      uglifyOptions: {
        compress: { drop_console: true },
      }
    }
}
```

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
    build: {
      chainWebpack(chain) {
        chain.optimization.minimizer('js').tap((args) => {
          args[0].terserOptions.compress.drop_console = true
          args[0].terserOptions.compress.drop_debugger = true
          return args
        })
      }
    }
}
```

All of which produce the below output.

`quasar inspect -c build -p optimization.minimizer`

**output**

```js
[
  TerserPlugin {
    options: {
      test: /\.[cm]?js(\?.*)?$/i {
        [lastIndex]: 0
      },
      minimizer: {
        options: {
          compress: {
            drop_console: true,
            drop_debugger: true
          }
        }
      }
    }
]
```

**eslintrc.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    // allow async-await
    'generator-star-spacing': 'off',
    // allow paren-less arrow functions
    'arrow-parens': 'off',
    'one-var': 'off',
    'optional-chaning': 0,
    'import/first': 'off',
    'import/named': 'error',
    'import/namespace': 'error',
    'import/default': 'error',
    'import/export': 'error',
    'import/extensions': 'off',
    'import/no-unresolved': 'off',
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': 'off',
    'prefer-promise-reject-errors': 'off',
    'vue/multi-word-component-names': 0,
    // allow debugger during development only
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody comes across the same issue I was able to figure it out.

I was using `node-polyfill` and I am not 100% what it did but it stopped Terser from removing console.

**Original (Broken version)**

```js
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = function (api) {
    build: {

      chainWebpack(chain) {
        chain.optimization.minimizer('js').tap((args) => {
          args[0].terserOptions.compress.drop_console = true
          args[0].terserOptions.compress.drop_debugger = true
          return args
        })

       chain.plugin('node-polyfill').use(new NodePolyfillPlugin())
      }
    }
}
```

**Working version**

```js
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = function (api) {
    build: {
      chainWebpack(chain) {
        chain.optimization.minimizer('js').tap((args) => {
          args[0].terserOptions.compress.drop_console = true
          args[0].terserOptions.compress.drop_debugger = true
          return args
        })
       chain.plugin('node-polyfill').use(
         new NodePolyfillPlugin({
           excludeAliases: ['console'],
         }),
        )
      }
    }
}
```